# How does git store resolved conflicts after merges and its author history

Tags: git

Today I finished reading the book chapter about the internals of git and I think I got a good overview of how git works.

But what I still don't understand is how and where git stores the author information of each line (resolved conflict) after a conflict got resolved.

As far as I understood commits just create 4 elements, and none of them cover a `line <==> author relationship`

```
helloworld.txt
This line (1) got accepted from branch foo by author foo
This line (2) got accepted from branch bar by author bar
```

Comment: Are you referring to the merge commit's author, or the authors of the commits that were parents of the merge commit?

Comment: Sorry, I am referring to the author of the parent commits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Git doesn't *store* that at all.  Git *recomputes* this kind of information, every time you ask about it.

Each commit *stores* a full snapshot of every file.  So file *F* in commit `a123456` is "authored" by whoever committed `a123456`.  That's not very *interesting*, at least, not on its own.

But each commit also stores, in its metadata, the hash ID of some set of *parent* commits.  Most commits have exactly one parent: perhaps the commit *before* `a123456` is `3141592`, for instance.  File *F* is probably in this earlier commit as well.  If we *compare* the *content* of file *F* in commit `3141592` with that of file *F* in `a123456`, maybe some lines are *different*.  If that's the case, we can claim that whoever made `a123456` really did write those particular lines, and whoever made `3141592` wrote the earlier lines.

But wait!  `3141592` also has a parent, such as `2147483`.  *That* commit probably has file *F* too.  If so, we repeat the comparing process: did the author of `3141592` *change* some lines, or simply carry the file through from before?  Or, if `2147483` does not have *F* after all, we can deduce that all of these lines were authored by whoever made `3141592`.

Note how Git has to start at the *end* of some linear chain of commits and work backwards.  A program like `git blame` "assigns ownership" of some source-code line of some file when, during this backwards walk, the line *changes* to read however it does in the final commit.  If it doesn't change, we don't yet know who to say wrote the line: we have to keep going back.

#### What about merges?

A *merge* commit stores the same snapshot as any non-merge commit, but instead of containing the hash ID of *one* parent, it has the hash ID of *two* parent commits.  So if we have a merge commit in hand, we can compare it to *either* parent.  Suppose file *F* is in merge commit `M`, and `M` has parents `J` and `L`.  If `F` exactly matches *both* parents' copies, *F* is probably not changed all the way back to the merge base:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M
         \    /
          K--L
```

The *F* in `M` probably matches file *F* in `H`, and was not changed in any of either set of commits between `H` and `M`.

But if the *F* in `M` matches the *F* in `J`, and *doesn't* match the *F* in `L`, why then, we must have picked the copy in `J` when merging.  So the copy in `L` probably matches the copy in `H`, while the one in `J` is probably different.  We should walk from `M` to `J` to "assign blame" for changes in *F*.

This is particularly weird since we follow the parent that *didn't* change the file.  But that's how `git log`'s **History Simplification** works: when doing history simplification, `git log` picks some parent in which a file *didn't* change, and goes down just that one leg of history.<sup>1</sup>

If `M`'s *F* doesn't match *either* of its inputs, both lines of commits must have contributed.  Was there a merge conflict?  We have no idea: we only know that the *snapshot* in `M` does not match either of the two snapshots in `J` and `L`.  The `git log` command will in this case *not* simplify away one leg of the merge.  What `git blame` will do is a bit of a mystery as it has never really been documented (and the algorithms for blame have evolved over time).

---

<sup>1</sup>There is a detailed description of how this works in [the `git log` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log), using the word TREESAME.  Git looks not just at *one* file, but rather at *every retained file*, with history simplification normally being turned on by mentioning particular pathnames.  The pathnames control which paths are retained, and which are stripped, in order to compare the saved snapshots in each commit, to determine TREESAME-ness.

Here, `git blame`'s documentation is a little weak on detail.

Comment: That answer is pure gold! Why can't I give someone bounties afterwards. Thank you so much!

Comment: Agree, that is a pretty great answer! Thanks @torek

Answer (score 1):

One more addon on to of [@torec answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59573780/how-does-git-store-resolved-conflicts-after-merges-and-its-author-history#59574129)

Git has another "hidden option" `git rerere`.

#### [`git rerere`](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/fix-conflicts-only-once-with-git-rerere-7d116b2cec67#.d8f95i5j7)

**R**ecorded **R**eused **R**esolution

Once `rerere` is enabled git will **store** the following information:

- The result of the conflict
- The solution (resolved) file

---

```
# enabled the option to record the 
git config --global rerere.enabled true
```

The output of the `rerere` once it resolves conflicts:

```
$ tree .git/rr-cache
.git/rr-cache
└── f08b1.... (40 digits SHA-1)
    ├── postimage
    └── preimage
```

---

By the way, if you prefer rerere to auto-stage files it solved (I do), you can ask it to: you just need to tweak your configuration like so:

```
git config --global rerere.autoupdate true
```

[image]

Comment: Important: `rerere` is *not permanent* (vs commits, which are, or mostly are) and generally not copied across clones.

Comment: `rerere` is not "sync" between repositories and like `reflog` is only locally

Comment: It does have a ref-like-file (`MERGE_RR`) which you could, if you wanted, copy to some set of transferrable refs; the individual rerere chunks are stored as Git blob objects, and hence transferrable. (There's no built in way to do this, though, and the file format is undocumented.)

Comment: I know and i do use it in my Jenkins Servers across nodes